# Java format an Array consisting of Strings

Tags: java

I want to output the contents of an Array showing 3 items per line.

It should be something like this:

```
ITEM1 ITEM2  ITEM3  
ITEM4 ITEM5  ITEM6    
ITEM7
```

I tried the following:

```java
if(a%3 == 0){
    //Code for adding line break
}
```

But this won't work because the condition for the first element is true and the line break comes after it.

What I get is:

```
ITEM1 
ITEM2  ITEM3 ITEM4 
ITEM5  ITEM6 ITEM7
```

Comment: Please include the code.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to add a line break after every three elements, you need to add the break after indices 2,5,8,... of the array.

You can achieve this with :

```
if ((a+1)%3 == 0) { 
    //Code for adding line break
}
```

Answer (score 1):

a is 0 for STRING 1, a+1 should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that changing the condition to `a % 3 == 2` will solve the problem:

```
Iterator<String> it = Iterators.cycle("entry1", "entry2", "entry3");
for (int i = 0 ; i  < 10 ; i++) {
    System.out.print( it.next() );
    if (i % 3 == 2)
        System.out.println();
}
```

Outputs

```
entry1entry2entry3
entry1entry2entry3
entry1entry2entry3
entry1
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code and remember java(and many programming languages) are zero based indexing. Which means it starts counting from zero, as 0, 1, 2, 3, ...

```
String[] arr = {"STRING 1",  "STRING 2", "STRING 3", "STRING 4", "STRING 5", "STRING 6", "STRING 7"};

    for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(arr[i]);
        if((i + 1)%3 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```